# Rails search through array of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, include, conditional-statements

I have an array of arrays like so: `[[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]]`.  I want to check whether the larger array contains arrays of a given number without regard to the animal element of the array. I also *do not want to loop* through the array because this would become computationally heavy.

So something like `@boolean = bigArray.include?([2, *])`, except something that actually works...

Comment: Whether explicit or implicit, one way or another, you're looping. There is no magic way of stepping through an array and examining each element without a loop. If you are that concerned with performance, you've chosen the wrong container for your data.

Comment: Also, you've given us a test case where the keys are duplicated but not told us what you expect to happen. Should your `bigArray.include...` return `[2, "cat"]`, or should it return `["cat", "bird"]`, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible solutions. Detect the element in the array or convert the array into a `Hash`

**1.** Use [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect), it will stop as soon as it finds a match and return it, `nil` otherwise.

```
> a = [[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]]
 => [[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]] 
> a.detect{ |(n, _)| n == 2 }
 => [2, "cat"]
> a.detect{ |(n, _)| n == 10 }
 => nil
```

If you want to add this to the `Array` class like your example, and force it to return a boolean, do this:

```
class Array
  def custom_include?(num)
    !!detect{ |(n, _)| num == n }
  end
end
```

Example:

```
> a.custom_include?(2)
 => true 
> a.custom_include?(10)
 => false
```

**2.** If you don't care about the colliding keys, you could convert the array into a `Hash` and see if the key exists.

```
> a = [[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]]
 => [[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]] 
> Hash[a][2]
 => "bird"
> Hash[a][10]
 => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

One very simple way that doesn't involve looping is to convert the structure to a hash. Your arrays happen to be in an ideal format for this:

```
values = [[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]]

Hash[values][2] # "bird"
```

You will lose the first value for each key, but it will serve to show whether a key exists.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this:

```
arr = [[1, "dog"], [2, "cat"], [2, "bird"], [3, "monkey"]]
arr.assoc(2)
```

it will return [2, cat]

in array if element is not exist

```
arr.assoc(10)
```

returns nil